# Android YouTube API memory leak when using RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-youtube-api, leakcanary

I have a `RecyclerView` with a list of pictures and YouTube thumbnails. If the user clicks on a YouTube thumbnail, it opens a new activity that displays an embedded YouTube video in the top half (using the `YouTube Android Player API` Fragment) and a description, title, etc. in the bottom half.

My problem is, no matter how I try implementing the `YouTube Android Player API`, Android Studio & [Leak Canary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary/) will always show it's leaking when I press the back button to return to my `RecyclerView`. I'm rather new to `LeakCanary`, and Android developing as a whole. If there is any more detail I can provide of the leak, let me know and I will edit this post to include it.

I've tried many ways to get this to work, also both way's `YouTube` suggested, `YouTubePlayerFragment` and `YouTubePlayerView`. At this point, I don't know what else to do. This only happens when I use the `YouTube API`, if I just displays a picture, my `Activity` doesn't leak. Any help is greatly appreciated, I'm ready to pull my hair out.

**LeakCanary**

`YouTubePlayerActivity` is my class, it's not in the `YouTube API`. Also, expanding any of the `LeakCanary` traces do not reveal any detail.

[image: Youtube Leak Canary]

**RecyclerView**

This is my `onBindViewHolder()` where I set my `onClickListener()` that opens my `YouTubePlayerActivity`.

```
mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Context context = v.getContext();

                Intent youtubeIntent = new Intent(context,YouTubePlayerActivity.class);

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                bundle.putString("foo", object.getUrl());
                bundle.putString("foo1", object.getDescription());

                youtubeIntent.putExtras(bundle);

                context.startActivity(youtubeIntent, bundle);

               }
        });
```

**YouTubePlayerActivity.class**

A slimmed down version of the class where my YouTube player is displayed. This was the last of many ways I tried implementing it. However, the leak was present no matter how I tried implementing it.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.detail_main_youtube);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    url = bundle.getString("foo");
    description = bundle.getString("foo1");


    TextView detailDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_detail_description_youtube);
detailDescription.setText(description);

    myFragment = PlayerYouTubeFrag.newInstance("Some random YouTube Id");
    myTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    myTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    myTransaction.replace(R.id.youtube_fragment, myFragment).commit();

}
```

**PlayerYouTubeFrag**

```
public class PlayerYouTubeFrag extends YouTubePlayerFragment {

private YouTubePlayer activePlayer;

public static PlayerYouTubeFrag newInstance(String youTubeId) {

    PlayerYouTubeFrag playerYouTubeFrag = new PlayerYouTubeFrag();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("youTubeId", youTubeId);

    playerYouTubeFrag.setArguments(bundle);
    playerYouTubeFrag.init();
    return playerYouTubeFrag;
}

private void init() {

    initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
            activePlayer = player;
            activePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
            if (!wasRestored) {
                activePlayer.loadVideo(getArguments().getString("youTubeId"), 0);

            }
        }
    });
}

}
```

**XML layout**

This is my `YouTubePlayerActivity`'s xml Frame Layout, which is replaced by the Fragment.

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/detail_main_youtube"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/backgroundColor">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view_youtube"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_detail_description_youtube"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/darkTextColor"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please add the RecyclerView Adapter code.

Comment: can you replace                          Intent youtubeIntent = newIntent(context,YouTubePlayerActivity.class);   by          Intent youtubeIntent = newIntent(getApplicationContext(),YouTubePlayerActivity.class); for once and check if it crashes ?

Comment: @Drew Szurko did you find a solution?

Comment: @ymerdrengene it's been a while, but I if I remember correctly, I did not find a solution.

Comment: @DrewSzurko OK.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in your `PlayerYouTubeFrag` code those lines :

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    activePlayer.release();
    activePlayer = null;
}
```